# The expected value and variance for the sum of 4 dice rolls only if a coin gives Head

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-variance

**Edited:**
toss a fair coin 4 times and then roll a fair 6-side dice whenever the coin gives a head H.

Let X be the sum of the dice rolls.

How to calculate `E[X]` and `var(X)`?

For `E[X]` I tried the following:

```
p(dice=1|H) = 1/12
p(dice=2|H) = 1/12
```

and so on.

So `E[X_i] =  1/12 (1+2+3+4+5+6) = 21/12`
==> `E[X] = 4 * E[X=i] = 21/3 = 7`

For the variance, I tried using the following formula:
`var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2` but it is not clear how to calculate `E[X^2]`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please explain what it means to "get H" after tossing a coin four times.  Are you trying to say that you repeat a particular experiment four times, where the experiment consists of flipping a coin and rolling a single die?  Your notation is obscure, in particular the part where you claim "21/4 = 7"!

Comment: @whuber edited.

Comment: +1.  Some hints: (i) work out $E[X]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ for a *single* iteration.  (ii) If you don't roll a die, that's the same as adding $0$ to the sum.  Therefore there are seven possible outcomes of your experiment: $0, 1, \ldots, 6.$ (iii) Work out the chances of each outcome.  (iv) Apply the standard formulas for expectation, now that you know the outcomes and their probabilities.

Comment: @whuber following your hints I have the following:

for 1 iteration, $X_i$ has values of 0 with prob 1/2 and 1 to 6 with prob 1/12 each
so $E[X_i] = 1/12(1+2+3+4+5+6) = 7/4$ and $var(E_i) = E[(X_i)^2] - E[X_i]^2$. We calculate $E[(X_i)^2] = 1/12(1+4+9+16+25+36) = 91/12$ and $E[X_i]^2 = 49/16 ==> var(E_i) = 217/48$. Finally for 4 iterations we have $E[X] = 4(E[X_i]) = 7$ and $var(X) = 16.var(X_i) = 217/3 $. I Hope this is correct.